# PHPUnit test fails for assertStatus(200) in my laravel project

Tags: php, laravel-5.6, phpunit

I have a Unit Test file with the following test method

```
    <?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class IndustryTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testURL()
    {
        $response = $this->get('admin/industry/index');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

In my `routes/web.php`  file, I have the following code:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'prevent-back-history'],function() {
    Route::group([ 'middleware' => 'admin'], function () {
       Route::get('admin/industry/index', 'IndustrymapController@industry_index');
    });
});
```

IndustrymapController.php has the following code:

```
public function industry_index()
{
    //get all available industries
    $industries = DB::connection('mysql_company_masterdb')
        ->table('tbl_industry_type')
        ->whereNull('deleted_at')
        ->get();
    return View('admin.IndustryMaster.index')
        ->with('industries',$industries);
}
```

I have a view file inside `admin/IndustryMaster/index.php` which works fine in the browser.

When I run `.\vendor\bin\phpunit` command in the terminal, however, it gives the following error:

```
PHPUnit 7.5.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.1.12
Configuration: C:\xampp\htdocs\selfcomply\phpunit.xml

F                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 294 ms, Memory: 14.00MB

There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Unit\IndustryTest::testURL
Expected status code 200 but received 302.
Failed asserting that false is true.

C:\xampp\htdocs\selfcomply\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse.php:78
C:\xampp\htdocs\selfcomply\tests\Unit\IndustryTest.php:21

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

If my code runs fine in the browser, why does the test fail?
I think it has something to do with the URL I have given

```
$response = $this->get('admin/industry/index');
```

**EDIT**

Following is my code in `admin` middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Sentinel;

class SentinelAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(!Sentinel::check())
            return redirect('signin')->with('info', 'You must be logged in!');

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is in your `admin` middleware? your test does not show you logging in/acting as an admin or any user, the 302 (redirection) is probably triggered there.

Comment: check my edit @naamhierzo

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what Sentinal is, see [testing session and authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/http-tests#session-and-authentication) specifically the `actingAs` method

Comment: Sentinel is the authentication and authorization system in Laravel which authenticates the user while logging in.

Comment: I checked my error log files where it shows `trying to get property of non object` near the line `Sentinel::getUser()->id` which indicates that `Sentinel` is causing the problem. But I don't understand why and how to solve it